# Debugging Mobile Safari on a Linux or Windows Machine

Tags: safari, mobile-safari

I know it's possible to debug mobile Safari through this [method](http://www.screenr.com/GYZ8).  It requires you to have Safari installed on your computer.  Mobile Safari is emulated on your desktop Safari to give you standard web dev features.

Safari was discontinued on Windows a few years ago.  Is this possible on a non-Mac machine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. You can use [ios-webkit-debug-proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy) and Chrome. It is slower than OS-X and Safari, but tolerable and you may have some issues when Chrome's developer tools don't quite match Safari, but it's much better than nothing.

I have not been able to get the 'chrome-devtools' URL working, so I just go to localhost:9222/ in Chrome after connecting my phone and starting the ios-webkit-debug-proxy.

I've had issues with ios-webkit-debug-proxy crashing or hanging - I have found it more reliable to restart it for each debugging session.